# RFCOMM Bluetooth Direct Connection: from BlueCove to In The Hand 32Feet

Tags: java, c#, bluetooth, bluecove, 32feet

This code works fine using [Java Bluecove Bluetooh Library](http://www.bluecove.org/). It's just a main method to probe a RFCCOMM direct connection.

I'm trying to do the same in C# based on ["In The Hand 32Feet"](https://32feet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) utility libray i would like send a text command and receive a response from device.

**For Java Based On BlueCove** ( Works fine ! )

```
String serverURL = "btspp://XXXXXXXXXXXX:1;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false";     
StreamConnection sc =  (StreamConnection) MicroeditionConnector.open(serverURL);
DataOutputStream  os = sc.openDataOutputStream();

String text = "Send command";
byte data[] = text.getBytes();

os.write(data);
os.flush();
os.close();      

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.openInputStream()));
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
      out.append(line);
 }
System.out.println("Receive data" + out.toString());
reader.close();
```

**For C# Based On  In The Hand 32 Feet**

This is my current attempt at converting it into to c#.... but the problem is that I haven't access to peerStream is closed ? (*always return CanRead to false*)  .

As you can see in the Java BlueCove Sample is possible to open a connection with a double purpose : OutputStream to write commands and a InputStream to read the result sequentially

Can I do this in another way?

```
String address = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
Guid mUUID = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000500b34fb");

BluetoothAddress addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse(address);
var btEndpoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, mUUID);
var btClient = new BluetoothClient();
btClient.connect(btEndpoint);

Stream peerStream = btClient.GetStream();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(peerStream))
{
   sw.WriteLine("Send command");
   sw.Flush();
   sw.Close();
}

if (peerStream.CanRead) 
{
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(peerStream))
   {
   while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("Receive data" + sr.ReadLine());
      }
   sr.Close();
   }       
}
btClient.Close();
btClient.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the call to sw.Close() closes the underlying stream as well, an therefore you cant read from peerStream after closing sw.

I would try something like this:

```
        String address = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
        Guid mUUID = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000500b34fb");

        BluetoothAddress addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse(address);
        var btEndpoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, mUUID);
        var btClient = new BluetoothClient();
        btClient.connect(btEndpoint);

        using (Stream peerStream = btClient.GetStream())
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(peerStream))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Send command");
            sw.Flush();

            if (peerStream.CanRead)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(peerStream))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Receive data" + sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```